# Texture painting applies color backwards

Tags: texture-painting

I am trying to paint the texture of my character but when I try to paint the Surface the edge on the other side gets painted.
For better understanding I added a Little Sketch.
Hope for help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like inverted normals. You can use Ctrl + N to recalculate normals and then you can select the direction in the Tools panel.

Comment: That was the answer. I already tried that but with Shift+N.